# Error when compiling : incompatible types and similar warnings ( picture attached )

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that returns the inverse of an array using recursivity but I keep getting these warnings :

[image: these warnings]

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int inv( float* t[],int n)
{   float u;
    if (n==0) return 0;
    else
    {
        u=*t;
        *t=*(t+n);
        *(t+n)=u;
        return(inv(*(t+1),n-1));
    }

}

int main()
{
    float t[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int n=sizeof t /sizeof *t;
    int i=0;
    inv(t,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)printf("%f",t[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `float* t[]` -> `float* t`.

Comment: `float *t[]` declares `t` as an array of *pointers* to `float`.  So `*t` has type `float *`, not `float`.  You have too many levels of indirection.

Comment: Plese do not add pictures of text. Instead just copy&paste the text messages into your question.

Comment: After you fix the parameter type to `float* t`, the next problem is that `*(t+n)` is an out of bounds dereference because `main` calls `inv` with `n` set to the length of the array. Also the recursive call `inv(*(t+1), n-1)` in the `return` statement has the wrong parameter type. I guess it should be `inv(t+1, n-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> int inv( float* t[],int n)

Here, `float* t[]` declares an array of pointers. Please note that `*t[i] = *(*(t+i))`

For i = 0, `*(*(t+i)) = *(*(t)) = *(*t)`.

Here, `*t` is of type `float*`, and `u` is of type float.

Using the expression `u=*t;` gives you that error (assigning `float*` value to `float`)

**Solution :**  Change `int inv( float* t[],int n)`  to `int inv( float t[],int n)`

Answer (score 0):

I use a procedure to arrange the array elements in descending order

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void revs(int i, int n, float *arr)
{
   if(i==n)
  {
     return ;
  }
  else
  {
       revs(i+1, n, arr);
       printf("%.f ", arr[i]);
  }
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    float t[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int n=sizeof t /sizeof t[0];
    int i=0;
    revs(0,n,t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the intended action of OP's function `inv` is to reverse the elements of an array of `n` `float` values in place, using recursion.

In the original `inv` code, the parameter declaration `float* t[]` will be adjusted to be equivalent to `float** t` by the compiler. This needs to be changed to `float t[]` or equivalently `float* t`.

In the original `inv` code, the return value is either `0` or the result of the recursive call to itself, which can only be `0`. Therefore the return value is of no use. It would be better to change the return type of the function to `void`.

In the `inv` function, the parameter `n` is set to the length of the array in the initial call from `main`. The function swaps the values of elements at indices 0 and `n` before recursing, but there is no element at index `n`. The last element has index `n-1`. The function should swap the elements at indices 0 and `n-1` before recursing. After swapping the first and last elements, the remaining `n-2` elements with indices from 1 to `n-2` can be swapped by a recursive call. The original `inv` code uses the value `n-1` in the recursive call, but it should be `n-2`.

If `n` is less than 2, the `inv` function does not need to do anything.

A possible implementation of `inv` based on OP's original code follows:

```
void inv(float* t,int n)
{   
    float u;
    if (n>=2)
    {
        u=*t;
        *t=*(t+n-1);
        *(t+n-1)=u;
        inv(t+1,n-2));
    }
}
```

The same function can be written using array subscripting operators as follows:

```
void inv(float t[],int n)
{   
    float u;
    if (n>=2)
    {
        u=t[0];
        t[0]=t[n-1];
        t[n-1]=u;
        inv(&t[1],n-2));
    }
}
```